# Reusing NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsxmlparser

in a class i'm writing i'll most likely have to use NSXMLParser twice to parse two different xml's, and i'm wondering which approach should i use?
- release the parser after it finished parsing url and reinitialize when need to parse the second url?
- use different class as delegate for parsing other url?
- or something else?

thanks
peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my own personal experience, I've commonly had to parse several different REST xml responses and for each of them I inherit a base class and create one class per request/response/parse. IMHO although this isn't *clean* code, I honestly find it impossible to write *clean* code when dealing with a SAX-style parser.

My advice would be separate calls and perhaps separate classes if you don't want a bunch of if-else's in your code. Now if the XML is very similar, it could be a different story...

Comment: so that means pretty much assigning a new delegate to second parser. fair enough. thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I have written a class which implements the parser methods and you just have to pass it a string (your url). It returns with an array of elements. It may be of use to you.

You can download it here: http://www.kieranmcgrady.me/helper-classes-for-parsing-xml-files

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've often made classes to parse each response type that I expected to see, you *can* reuse an NSXMLParser, but I really haven't seen a need to.

Depending on your requirements you may want to just read the responses into nested NSDictionaries, then deal with accessing the elements that you need directly from the dictionaries.